# Create 7 digit codes as ID for every row

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014

I want to generate ID in SQL server 2014 which will be of varchar(7). I am aware of identity column but what I want to do is create ID's based on SEQ_ID of a table. It should start with C and length is 7 Below is an example:-

```
TABLE A
   SEQ_NO       NAME
    1             a
    12             b
    30             c
    401            d
```

Output required is:-

```
SEQ    ID         NAME
1    C000001       a   
12   C000012        b
30   C000030        c
401  C000401         d
```

Thought of using replicate and Identity column but that does not help me get the desired output. Any thoughts?

Comment: My thought is wonder what your plan is for your 10 millionth row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are on 2014, yet another option is Format().

To be clear, Format() has some great features, but it is not known to be a high performer.

```
Select 'C'+format(Seq,'000000')
```

Returns (for example)

```
C000012
```

Comment: I like how you spin the performance as 'not known to be a higher performer' instead of 'known to be a poor performer'!

Comment: @SqlZim I've been married for years. Learned how to spin things from my wifte  for example she says "I saved $600" while I'm thinking "No, you spent $2,800"

Answer (score 2):

using `right()`

```
select 'C'+right('000000'+convert(varchar(6),seq_no),6)
```

---

demo:

```
create table a (seq_no int, name varchar(16))
insert into a values
 (1 ,'a') ,(12 ,'b') ,(30 ,'c') ,(401,'d') 

select *
  , Id = 'C'+right('000000'+convert(varchar(6),seq_no),6)
from a
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/XVQ74081

returns:

```
+--------+------+---------+
| seq_no | name |   Id    |
+--------+------+---------+
|      1 | a    | C000001 |
|     12 | b    | C000012 |
|     30 | c    | C000030 |
|    401 | d    | C000401 |
+--------+------+---------+
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get it using [REPLICATE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/replicate-transact-sql).

```
SELECT SEQ_NO AS SEQ,
       CONCAT('C', REPLICATE('0', 6 - LEN(SQL_NO)), CAST(SEQ_NO AS VARCHAR(10))) ID
       NAME
FROM   YOUR_TABLE;
```

Comment: Thanks for showing me how we can use replicate here!

Comment: I'm glad to help.